# HTTP Mock Response class has 0 coverage

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, httpcalloutmock

I have created a mock response to gain coverage for a hhtp request, as per the following documentation:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Here is my class:

```
public class SASProposalGenerationClass { 

    private final Opportunity oppty;

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getUIThemeDescription() {
        String theme = UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed();
        return theme;
    }

    public SASProposalGenerationClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        this.oppty = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Opportunity getParentOpportunity(String opportunityId){
        if(opportunityId == null){
            return null;
        }

        Opportunity o = [SELECT Id, Name, Owner.Name, Owner.Email, Vertical_Group__c, Billing_Entity__r.Name, Billing_Entity__r.Client_Account__c, Billing_Entity__r.Client_Account__r.Name, Billing_Entity__c, Billing_Entity__r.ABN__c, Billing_Entity__r.ACN__c, Campaign_Start_Date__c, Campaign_End_Date__c, Account.Name, Billing_Entity__r.Legal_Entity__c, Billing_Entity__r.REA_ID__c, Billing_Entity__r.CID__c, Owner.SAS_ID__c, Owner.SAS_Ad_Trafficker__c, Owner.SAS_Ad_Trafficker__r.SAS_ID__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:opportunityId];
        return o;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getSASProposalId(String opportunityId, String reqBody) {

        // Instantiate a new http object
        Http h = new Http();

        // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String url = 'http://sf-to-sas-sandbox.au.cloudhub.io/opportunities/' + opportunityId;
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(reqBody);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        // Send the request, and return a response
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        System.debug('response:--> ' + res.getBody());

        String responseString = String.valueOf(res.getBody());

        return responseString;
    }

}
```

and my test class:

```
@isTest
public class SASProposalGenerationClass_Test { 

    static testMethod void testSASProposalGeneration() {

        //Need an agency Account
        Account agency = DataFactory.generateSingleAccount();
        INSERT agency;

        //Need a contact
        Contact contact = DataFactory.generateSingleContact();
        contact.AccountId = agency.Id;
        INSERT contact;

        //Need an advertiser account
        Account advertiser = DataFactory.generateSingleAccount();
        INSERT advertiser;

        //Need a billing Entity
        SAGE_Billing_Details__c BE = DataFactory.generateSingleBillingEntity();
        BE.Billing_Account__c = agency.id;
        BE.Client_Account__c = advertiser.Id;
        BE.Contact__c = contact.Id;
        INSERT BE;

        //Need an opportunuty
        Opportunity op = DataFactory.generateSingleOpportunity();
        op.Billing_Entity__c = BE.Id;
        op.AccountId = advertiser.Id;
        //set opportunity record type to Media Opportunity
        List<RecordType> rtList = new List<RecordType>([SELECT ID FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Media Opportunity' AND SObjectType = 'Opportunity' LIMIT 1]);
        op.RecordTypeId = rtList[0].Id;
        INSERT op;

        Test.startTest();
            //Aura Component environment test
            String currentTheme = SASProposalGenerationClass.getUIThemeDescription();

            //get all opportunity details
            Opportunity currentOp = SASProposalGenerationClass.getParentOpportunity(op.Id);

            //set test mock http callout
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new SASProposalGenerationClass_MockResponse());
            String res = SASProposalGenerationClass.getSASProposalId(op.Id, '{test:test}');

            //VF page test environment
            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',op.Id);
            ApexPages.StandardController stdOpp = new ApexPages.StandardController(op);
            SASProposalGenerationClass objSASProposalGenerationClass = new SASProposalGenerationClass(stdOpp);

        Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

and finally my mock response:

```
@isTest
global class SASProposalGenerationClass_MockResponse implements HttpCalloutMock { 

    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        //System.assertEquals('http://sf-to-sas-sandbox.au.cloudhub.io/opportunities/' + opportunityId, req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"proposalId":"001827262524"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }

}
```

Via the test class the SASProposalGenerationClass has 95% coverage, however the Mock HTTP Response is being given 0% coverage, bringing down my org average.

Is there a way to resolve this issue? Considering the main class is getting coverage on the callout I can assume that the mock is being run, however it is showing 0% coverage which is confusing me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Mock is annotated with isTest and thus does not count in overall coverage

There is a small bug when creating classes in that if from an IDE you don't specify it is a test class and thus isTest is not present on insert it will mess up you coverage.

Simply delete the mock class and recreate it ensuring the isTest annotation is present on creation.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering this so quickly but as soon as I hit "Post" I thought of a resolution.

I removed the @isTest declaration form the mock response and ran the test class again. Now the mock response has 100% coverage.

I considered removing this as I resolved it myself however when I was googling I could not find any similar questions, and considering it goes against the advise from the official documentation I figured this may be useful to someone?

If this is inappropriate and should be deleted please feel free to do so (or alert me to do so).

Thanks!